# /usr/bin/zcat: Argument list too long

Tags: xargs, zcat

I have used the following a [guide](https://blobtoolkit.genomehubs.org/install/#databases) with these commands:

```
echo "accession\taccession.version\ttaxid\tgi" > reference_proteomes.taxid_map
zcat */*/*.idmapping.gz | grep "NCBI_TaxID" | awk '{print $1 "\t" $1 "\t" $3 "\t" 0}' >> reference_proteomes.taxid_map
```

I used `echo "accession\taccession.version\ttaxid\tgi" > reference_proteomes.taxid_map` & `zcat *.idmapping.gz | grep "NCBI_TaxID" | awk '{print $1 "\t" $1 "\t" $3 "\t" 0}' >> reference_proteomes.taxid_map`

but I received the messaged that the argument list is too long:`/usr/bin/zcat: Argument list too long`

so I have tried xargs in this: `find /Volumes/My\ Passport\ for\ Mac/uniprot | xargs zcat *.idmapping.gz | grep "NCBI_TaxID" | awk '{print $1 "\t" $1 "\t" $3 "\t" 0}' >> reference_proteomes.taxid_map`
but still received the long list argument message `-bash: /usr/bin/xargs: Argument list too long`, any suggestion?

Comment: Instead of `zcat */*/*.idmapping.gz | grep ...` you could do something like `( find . -name '*.idmapping.gz" | xargs zcat ) | grep ...`

Comment: so I have received long list message "zcat: can't stat: ./UP000000212_1234679.idmapping.gz (./UP000000212_1234679.idmapping.gz.Z): No such file or directory", the file name is something like "UP000000577_243231.idmapping.gz:, is there anything missing?

Comment: Hmm, it's assuming the old "compress" files. An alternative is `gunzip -c` -- so you can try to make it `( find . -name '*.idmapping.gz" | xargs gunzip -c ) | grep ...`

Comment: There's also a command `zgrep` you could try: `( find . -name '*.idmapping.gz' | xargs zgrep -h "NBCI_TaxID" ) | awk ...`

Comment: hmm, I tried 'zgrep' , I am not sure if it works, when I 'less reference_proteomes.taxid_map' , it's still empty : it only has 'accession\taccession.version\ttaxid\tgi' that line, that's it.

Comment: You could try to print a few lines to the terminal like this: `find. -name "*.idmapping.gz" | xargs gunzip -c | head -n 20`  Then you can see if `NBCI_TaxID` appears in the sample.  If not, you can search for some other value that does appear, i.e. use `zgrep -h "some other value"`. You can run your original command with the new search string as a test case -- it should produce a file that's longer than just the header line.

Comment: yes, I have seen a line "K8E169 NCBI_TaxID 1234679" in there, I think the issue happens because of typo on "NBCI", it should be "NCBI". Anyway, it works, no empty file,  thank you so much!